# Render buffer[] perfomance

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, bitmap, bufferedimage

I am having performance issues of rendering buffer[] to . My CPU is always running at near 100% efficiency. I tried using some ways like chopping buffer[] and then comparing, if the region changes, render that area but it doesn't work. Can someone help me with this or point me to a library that can help?

I'm working on an app that's almost like AnyDesk

Thank you very much.

Here is my code

```
 public void KVM_VideoCallback(IntPtr p_buffer, int width, int height, int channel)
        {
            byte[] Buffer;
            Buffer = new byte[width * height * 3];
            Buffer.Initialize();
            Marshal.Copy(p_buffer, Buffer, 0, (int)(width * height * 3));
            imageViewVM?.UpdateNewImage(Buffer, width, height, channel);
        }
 public void UpdateNewImage(byte[] buffer, int width, int height, int channel)
        {
            lock (updateBufferHandler)
            {
                iwI = width;
                ihI = height;
                stride = width * channel;
                Array.Clear(bufferCamera, 0, bufferCamera.Length);
                bufferCamera = buffer;
            }
            isUpdate = !isUpdate;
            if (isUpdate) return;
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                btmImage = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Bgr24, BitmapPalettes.Gray256, buffer, stride);
               
            });
        }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Dispatcher.Invoke`? Is this where the issue is or do you have the same issue if you temporary remove that line of code?

Comment: i tried it but it not working, Because I have a continuous screen capture device. and that captured image is converted as buffer[], and from that buffer[] is converted back to image. And that happens continuously in miliseconds the same way a cartoon is drawn.

Comment: Or do you mean change?